Why am I receiving this error in R v4.4.1?
I was trying to install the gsheet package in R 4.4.1 but I ran into an issue.
When I run the code install.packages("gsheet"), I receive the following error:
Warning in install.packages("gsheet") :
  'lib = "C:/Program Files/R/R-4.4.1/library"' is not writable
Error in install.packages("gsheet") : unable to install packages


Right.  Program Files is not generally user-writable.  You need to do that in an elevated administrator shell.

As mentioned by Tim Roberts comment Program Files is not generally a user-writable location. According to the R documentation you have a few options, I would suggest to Run R in an elevated terminal with Administrator privileges.
Reference:
https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rw-FAQ.html#Does-R-run-under-Windows-7_003f
